# sqlite,sqlalchemy and pandas when inserting multiple row with chinese characters

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy

In Python 2.7
with sqlite3:

## >>>>>>>>>>>i can do all the followings<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('History_1.db')
connection.text_factory=str
cursor =  connection.cursor()
cursor.executemany('insert into INDEX_BASIC_TABLE (code,name) values (?,?)', [("399333", "1wwo我wal阿斯蒂芬回家看"),("399333", "1阿道夫"),("399333", "1")])
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

with sqlalchemy:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///1.db', echo=engine_echo)
connection = engine.connect()
connection.text_factory=str
```

## >>>>>>>>>>>i can do this<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

```
connection.execute('insert into INDEX_BASIC_TABLE (code,name) values ("399333", "我")')
connection.execute('insert into INDEX_BASIC_TABLE (code,name) values ("399333", "的我"),("399333", "的我")')
```

## >>>>>>>>>>>but i cannot do this<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

```
connection.execute('insert into INDEX_BASIC_TABLE (code,name) values (?,?)', [("399333", "1wwo我wal阿斯蒂芬回家看"),("399333", "1阿道夫"),("399333", "1")])
connection.close()
```

with pandas, i cannot do the following if chinese characters in df where df is a pandas object:

```
df.to_sql('INDEX_BASIC_TABLE', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

all the 'i cannot do' above yield the following errors:
ProgrammingError: (sqlite3.ProgrammingError) You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.

why? are those bugs as sqlite3's orignial statements can do but sqlachemy and pandas cannot do? Or how can i solve these problems?
thank!

Comment: did you try it __without__ this line: `connection.text_factory=str`?

Comment: here is how i solve the problem:
with sqlalchemy:
connection.execute('insert into INDEX_BASIC_TABLE (code,name) values (?,?)', [("399333",u "1wwo我wal阿斯蒂芬回家看"),("399333", u"1阿道夫"),("399333", "1")])
connection.close()
Just put a 'u' before the string where it contains chinese characters.
if I want put pandas dataframe where it contains chinese characters, use an apply function. e.g :df['chinesename'].apply(lambda x:unicode(x,'utf-8'))

Comment: here is how i solve the problem: